# Beamer error due to pgf package

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pdftex

I keep getting following error when generating a simple slide on beamer.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This produces the error stack below with more detail in the picture. Any suggestion for a fix/solution?

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6630 64-bit)
entering extended mode
...
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfkeyssetevalue ...pandafter {\pgfkeys@expanded 
                                                  {#2}}}
l.17 \pgfkeys{/pgf/.is family}
```

[image: error pic]

Comment: May be you have to clean the files: `.aux`, `.out`, `.toc` etc

Comment: Your version of pdfTeX is way out of date (it doesn't support `\expanded`). How did you even manage to install such a recent version of PGF without also updating pdfTeX?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP problem cannot be reproduced by recent LaTeX installation. OP need to upgrade her/his ancient package.